# How to extend a template in go?

Tags: go, go-templates

Here is the problem: There are several `article`s on each page's `content` section and I'd like to insert a `likebar` template below each article.

So the `base.tmpl` is like:

```
<html>
  <head>    
    {{template "head.tmpl" .}}
  </head>
  <body>    
    {{template "content.tmpl" .}}   
   </body>
</html>
```

and in `article.tmpl` I want to have :

```
    {{define "content"}}    
          <div>article 1 
             {{template "likebar.tmpl" .}} 
          </div> 
          <div>article 2
             {{template "likebar.tmpl" .}} 
         </div>
       ... //these divs are generated dynamically
    {{end}}
```

How can I achieve this with `html/template`? 
I have tried to insert a `{{template "iconbar" .}}` in `base.tmpl` and then nested `{{template "likebar.tmpl" .}}` inside `{{define  "content"` but it failed with:

> Template File Error: html/template:base.tmpl:122:12: no such template
>   "likebar.tmpl"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only include / insert [associated templates](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Associated_templates).

If you have multiple template files, use [`template.ParseFiles()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseFiles) or [`template.ParseGlob()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseGlob) to parse them *all*, and the result template will have all the templates, already associated, so they can refer to each other.

If you do use the above functions to parse your templates, then the reason why it can't find `likebar.tmpl` is because you are referring to it by an invalid name (e.g. missing folder name).

When parsing from `string` source, you may use the [`Template.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Parse) method, which also associates nested templates to the top level template.

See these 2 working examples:

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(templ1))
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    t2 := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(templ2))
    template.Must(t2.Parse(templ2Like))
    if err := t2.Execute(os.Stdout, nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

const templ1 = `Base template #1
And included one: {{template "likebar"}}
{{define "likebar"}}I'm likebar #1.{{end}}
`

const templ2 = `Base template #2
And included one: {{template "likebar"}}
`

const templ2Like = `{{define "likebar"}}I'm likebar #2.{{end}}`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ozf4sUVYuj)):

```
Base template #1
And included one: I'm likebar #1.

Base template #2
And included one: I'm likebar #2.
```